# Есть ли слово "музыкальною"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, склонение, прилагательные

Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли слово "музыкальною"?

Answer (score 1):

[**музыкальный**](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9)
Прилагательное, качественное и относительное, тип склонения по классификации А. Зализняка — 1*a.
Музыкальная (ж.р.) — *музыкальной, музыкальною* (кем?чем? — тв.п.).

Слово существует, но употребляется нечасто.

*Веселая мышка в рояле жила,

Она **музыкальною** мышкой была

И часто под звуки рояля...*
**[Андрей Усачев. Веселая мышка](https://valya-15.livejournal.com/100463.html)**

***Музыкальною*** азбукою принято также называть учебники элементарной теории.

*Этот композитор отличался изумительною быстротою письма и **музыкальною** плодовитостью.*